# Display connection bars in the notification bar iff the signal strenth is below some threshold

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notification-bar, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Is there any way to display the connection bars in the notification bar if and only if the signal strength is below some threshold (e.g. 50%)?

---

The connection bar I am talking about is shown below:

[image]

I am only only interested in the connection bars when the signal strength is low.

I use a Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900A with Android 4.4.2.